# What are the differences between these sentences? (to do / to have done)

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense

Do you feel any difference between these two in each pair?

(1)
(a) Maria was happy **to have passed** the exam.
(b) Maria was happy **to pass** the exam.

(2)
(a) Maria is happy **to have passed** the exam.
(b) Maria is happy **to pass** the exam.

Comment: This sounds like an exam or homework question. You aren't asking us to do your homework for you, are you?

Comment: No, this is not an exam question. I'm a researcher and investigating how native English speakers understand the difference.

Comment: Why don't you try and tell us?

Comment: Ok, cool. I'm glad that this is legit. I had to ask because it's common for people to throw us their hw questions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it okay if I continue asking questions like this for my linguistics research?

Comment: I'm investigating the difference between what is written in grammar books and how native English speakers actually use the expressions to develop a new English grammar for Japanese learners of English. I have asked for opinions by using yahoo answers for a long time. Unfortunately, however, yahoo answer will be closed down shortly. I happened to find this site and tried positing a question.

Comment: @tak Very interesting research! Please take into account that the people answering questions here are a self-selected group of language professionals, language nerds, and language know-it-alls -- not representative of the average person on the street. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

> (1)
> (a) Maria was happy to have passed the exam.
> (b) Maria was happy to pass the exam.

> (2)
> (a) Maria is happy to have passed the exam.
> (b) Maria is happy to pass the exam.

In 1(b), passing the examination would make her happy.  It was not known if she passed.

2(b) is similar; it is not known if she has passed.

In 1(a), she passed the examination and was happy.

In 2(a), she has passed the examination and is happy.

Comment: How do 1b and 2b mean she may not have passed the exam? What do they fully mean then? Is she happily offering to pass the exam? This is more of an opinion comment than a fully explained answer.